# How many ministerial deferments were there during WWII for the United States?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, military, conscription

How many, or what percentage of eligible inductees were excused by way of a 2-D or 4-D during WWII?

Comment: Are you talking about the [draft classifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selective_Training_and_Service_Act_of_1940#Draft_classifications) that are listed as "deferred"? There are actually rather a lot of them, but there was no "II-D" among them.

Comment: @T.E.D. I would guess the OP misapplied the post 1948 classes, which does have 2-D and 4-D for these types of deferments. There's a IV-D deferment for ministers and divinity students in WW2 though.

Comment: Somewhere, I found those designations—maybe from Korea or Viet Nam?—that indicated being in college (II-S) or seminary (II-D) and IV-D, for actual ministers.  I guess the latter belongs in Classification V, according to this.  What I need to know is *how many* of these not-enlisted people there were during WWII (or during the selective service period from 1940-'48).  Thank you for this, though.

Comment: Well, to give one example, one of my grandfathers got deferred due to being employed in a vital wartime industry (the oil industry). That's a deferral, but not one of those two classes you are asking about. So are you interested in **all** deferrals, or just certain types of them.?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[25 MILITARY CLASSIFICATIONS For Draftees for WW2 through 1947](http://www.swarthmore.edu/Library/peace/conscientiousobjection/MilitaryClassifications.htm).
used by Selective Service.

Five major catagories.

> **I** -  Liable to military service in the order determined by the national drawing
>
> **II** - Temporary (dependency) discharge from draft; effective until Class I in the jurisdiction of the same Local Board was exhausted; registrants with both wife & children, or any father of  motherless children, where such wife & children were not mainly dependent upon the registrant’s labor for support; also, registrants whose wives could support themselves through employment
>
> **III** -  Temporary (dependency) discharge from draft; effective until Classes I & II in the jurisdiction of the same Local Board was exhausted; registrants who were responsible forchildren not their own & who were dependent on registrant’s labor for support; registrants who had aged, inform or invalid parents or grandparents mainly dependent on registrants' government employees
>
> **IV** -   Temporary (dependency) discharge from draft; effective until Classes I, II & III in the jurisdiction of the same Local Board was exhausted; any married registrant whose wife or children were mainly dependent on registrant’s labor for support; also included mariners employed in sea service
>
> **V**   - Exemption or discharge from draft; including:
>   - ordained ministers
>   - students who on May 18, 1917 had been prepared for ministry in a recognized theological or divinity school
>   - persons in the military or naval service of the United States (officers & enlisted men)
>   - alien enemies
>   - resident aliens
>   - persons found to be totally & permanently physically or mentally unfit for military service
>   - persons show to have been convicted of any crime designated as treason or felony, or an “infamous” crime
>   - licensed pilots actually employed in the pursuit of his vocation

---

You can get copies of the Selective Service Records from the national archives [here](https://www.archives.gov/st-louis/archival-programs/other-records/selective-service.html).

---

[The following shows the numbers of men who entered military service through the Selective Service System during WWII](https://www.sss.gov/About/History-And-Records/Induction-Statistics)

[Number of Inductions](https://www.sss.gov/About/History-And-Records/Induction-Statistics):   10,110,104

By year.
1040..............18,633.
1941.............923,842.
1942...........3,033,361.
1943...........3,323,970.
1944...........1,591,942.
1945.............945,862.
1946.............183,383.
1947...................0.

---

below taken from wikipedia's [US conscription](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_in_the_United_States#Conscientious_objectors_2) article

- 72,000 men registered as CO (conscientious objectors)
- 52,000 of those received CO status

  ---
- 25,000 of those entered the military in non combat roles.
- 12,000 went to civilian work camps
- 6,000 went to prison.

---

Draft evasion accounted for 4% of the total draftees.

- 373,000 evaders were investigated
- 16,000 were imprisoned.

Comment: This is getting close to what I need—thank you.  I guess I can go to the national archives for what I'm looking for.  I need the number of IV-D and II-D exemptions (I guess "deferment" was the wrong term).

Comment: @winonaww - Which again will be quite difficult, as **there was no such thing as II-D during WWII**